# Is LambdaB1S1 the same as Upstream O2?

Tags: o2-sensor

I have an Innova 3040C scan tool and a 2013 Hyundai Accent.  Under live data I have O2B1S2 which I believe is the downstream O2 sensor.  Oddly there is no O2S1B1 listed.  There is a LambdaB1S1 voltage reading.  I'm trying to track the possible causes of a 420 code.  My Lambda reads a consistently high .945 v which occasionally will jump as high as 1.2 and drop as low as .850.  It does not cycle as I would expect the upstream O2 to do.

Answer (score 1):

Easy to find out: unplug the sensor (electric supply) and see what the scantool tells. If it tells B1S2 you got your answer.

- Is your sensor warm enough?
- Does it react (correlate) to changes in throttle position
- especially cut off?
- does your throttle(flap) work correctly? (by cable or wire?) clean if neccessary

Comment: Doh!  Great idea.  Sensor is warm enough.  It does react to throttle but not as I would expect.  I was expecting to see the usual rich/lean pulse but I'm not seeing that.  STFT seems as expected -3/+3.  LTFT is consistently high which is the opposite of what I think I'm seeing with the high O2 reading (rich).  I would expect all fuel trims to be in the negative with the O2 showing rich.